# Como puedo obtener el nombre de las aplicaciones?

Tags: c#, windows, proceso

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de consola donde se me es requerido obtener el nombre de las aplicaciones que están siendo ejecutadas.

He intentado hacerlo con `Process.GetProcesses()` pero hay unas aplicaciones como por ejemplo **Visual Studio** sale  como `devenv.exe` y no el nombre como tal.

Quería saber si es posible con algún otro método traer el nombre que le corresponde a cada una de las aplicaciones.

Gracias!

Comment: a que llamas "nombre"? porque el ejecutable es el nombre de la aplicacion, o esperas el titulo de la ventana

Comment: El titulo de la ventana

Answer (score 1):

Ayudandonos de esta implementacion

[How to list all Windows Processes and their attributes (Task Manager like) with C# in WinForms](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/439/how-to-list-all-windows-processes-and-their-attributes-task-manager-like-with-c-in-winforms)

veras que se puede obtener informacion adicional del proceso con la ayuda de `WMI`, analiza el metodo `GetProcessExtraInformation()`

En este se ejecuta la query WMI: `Win32_Process`

```
string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
```

para conseguir la descripcion accede a la ruta del ejecutable y finalmente al la descripcion

```
FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(obj["ExecutablePath"].ToString());
response.Description = info.FileDescription;
```